# Algolia Restrict Index's data

Tags: laravel, algolia

I am trying to create a new index in Algolia which is identical with my first index but will have a different data from my first index. I want to have a contacts index for NZ and another for AU.

I used `indexOnly($index_name)` with a condition inside this function. But it is not working properly and I don't know if this function is what I need.

This is how I am creating it

```
class Contact extends Model {

  use AlgoliaEloquentTrait;

  protected $table = 'contacts';

  public $indices = ['contacts_local'];

  /** ALGOLIA SETTINGS */

  public function getAlgoliaRecord()
  {
    return fractal()->item($this)->transformWith(new ContactTransformer)->toArray();
  }

  private $index_name = 'contacts_local';

  public function indexOnly($index_name) {
    return $this->contact_country == 'New Zealand';
  }
}
```

I then run the reindex function.

The above method returns nothing in my `contacts_local` index.
Anything i'm doing wrong here?

I am using the same table in my database but the two indices will have different data depending on the `country` of the `contact`. Would this be possible in Algolia?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is doable with the Algolia Laravel/Eloquent integration. What I would do instead is:

- push all the records/contacts to the same (unique) index
- tag the records with their associated countries (in the `_tags` attribute)
- use Algolia's [Secured API Keys](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys#secured-api-keys) to hash-generate some keys that are restricted to a specific countries using the `tagFilters` (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/filtering-faceting#filter-by-tag)

This will be easier and as fast as having 1 index per country.